# Netbeans using comma as default. Why?

Tags: netbeans, configuration, decimal

**Hello guys and girls,
So, Netbeans (like most IDE's) use dots (.) to organize decimal places, right? 
I dont know why but my IDE began to use comma (,) to organize decimal places... even the outputs showed in the console are using commas. How can i change it back to default settings and start using dot in decimal places again?**

**PS: When i try to enter a number using dot and the decimal places (4.5, for example) i get this error message:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at EstruturasDeControle.If.main(If.java:16)
Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: See [Scanning doubles when I separate decimals with comma or dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42332273/2985643), though that is not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning input which expects a comma rather than a period as the separator for decimal values (or vice versa) is directly related to the `Locale` being used.

There are three ways of specifying the [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to resolve your problem:

1. You can specify the locale to be used by default as a parameter when NetBeans is started:

   `--locale <language[:country[:variant]]>`

   For example: `--locale en:US` for American English, and `--locale fr:FR` for French.

   This setting will apply for the current NetBeans session only.
2. You can permanently set the default locale used by NetBeans, by specifying it in the file **etc/netbeans.conf** within your NetBeans installation directory:

   - Open that file in any text editor.
   - Locate the line containing the text **netbeans_default_options**
   - Add the values to specify the language and country of the locale. for example, to set the locale to US English:
     `-J-Duser.language=en -J-Duser.country=US`
   - See the article [Change UI language to English on Netbeans IDE](https://pkolomeitsev.blogspot.com/2016/12/change-ui-language-to-english-on.html) for more details.
3. You can dynamically specify the `Locale` to be used at the application level within the code. For example, in your case you could set the locale used by your application's `Scanner` by calling `useLocale()`.

Your code code might look like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useLocale(Locale.US); // US locale, so period is expected for numeric input.
...
scanner.useLocale(Locale.FR); // France locale, so comma is expected for numeric input.
```

All three approaches can resolve your problem, and you can use any or all of them. Your specific needs determine the one(s) to be used.